# Will an SSRS report on Azure SQL Database work?

Tags: azure-sql-database, ssrs, reporting

Can we build an SSRS report using Visual Studio 2019 with Azure SQL server as PaaS mode?

We migrated to Azure Database from VM SQL Managed instance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can fetch the data from Azure SQL database but it does not include SSRS so you would need a separate install (Azure VM ?) for that.

Comment: Just a quick note that Power BI might be the answer for this.   Check out https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-sql/hosting-ssrs-databases-in-azure-sql-managed-instance/ba-p/1700197